# How to append into a list if it doesn't find anything that matches the list?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I want to make a print when my code doesn't find anything throughout the whole list.

This is my code:

```
new_list = ['There%is', 'None&of', 'Same&here']
a = new_list.split("%")
old_list = ['Stack%Hello', 'Over&You', 'flow&There']
condition = True
while condition:
    try:
        for i, items in zip(range(len(old_list)), old_list):
            old_list_value = old_list[i].split("%")
            if a[0] in items:
                if len(old_list_value[1]) < len(a[1]):
                    old_list[i] = new_list        
                    condition = False

                elif len(old_list_value[1]) > len(a[1]):
                    old_list[i] = new_lis
                    condition = False

            else:
                old_list.append(new_list)
                condition = False
                break

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

What I want do is: check every first word of each `%` and then I make a compare from old_list to check if there is the first word inside the old_list - if there is one then we replay it the old_list value with the new one.

elif if the word is longer than then the new_list word then we dont do anything.

How can I make so that if it doesn't find `if a[0] in items:` at the whole list then we add the new_list into old_list bascially?

Meaning it needs to first search for all words if it contains inside the old_list and if it is not then we append.

New edit:

Code:

```
new_list = ['There%is', 'None&of', 'Same&here']
a = new_list.split("%")
old_list = ['Stack%Hello', 'Over&You', 'flow&There']


for i, items in zip(range(len(old_list)), old_list):
    old_list_value = old_list[i].split("%")
    if a[0] in items:
        if len(old_list_value[1]) < len(a[1]):
            old_list[i] = new_list
            break


        elif len(old_list_value[1]) > len(a[1]):
            old_list[i] = new_list
            break


else:
    old_list.append(new_list)
    break
```

Comment: You don't need a break statement in the else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the for-else:

```
for item in items:
    if you_found_something:
        found_item = item
        break
else:
    print('No item found.')
    do_your_append_here
```

Basically the for-else answers the question if the for loop terminated without a break. Above we break when we find something therefore the `else` won't be executed but as far as your for loop terminates without a break statement, then the code in `else` will be executed.

Comment: In that case I dont need to actually do a while loop and stuff that I did?

Comment: That's correct. You might want to restructure your solution with this new syntax in mind, which should solve your problem.